# ip command in Mac OS X terminal

Tags: linux, macos, terminal.app

I use the command `ip link` in Linux. Now I want it on Mac OS X, but the Mac OS X terminal doesn't have `ip`. What should I use instead?

Comment: I think if the Linux community wants 'ip' to replace 'ifconfig' then it would be helpful for 'ip' to be available on both Unix and Linux.

Comment: If with the Linux community you mean the OSS community, they did they part with `iproute2mac` and the `iproute2` itself. The issue is that other Unix vendors don't even try to adopt it. Reasons they may have, but it is on their side.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can use `brew` to install `iproute2mac`. It's actually a Python wrapper that provides a very similar API that you'll likely find very familiar to the `ip` tool included with `iproute2` on Linux.

#### Installation

```
$ brew install iproute2mac
==> Installing iproute2mac from brona/homebrew-iproute2mac
==> Downloading https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac/archive/v1.0.3.zip
######################################################################## 100.0%
  /usr/local/Cellar/iproute2mac/1.0.3: 4 files,  24K, built in 2 seconds
```

#### Usage

Once installed you'll be given a command line tool that for all intent purposes mimics the `ip` command on Linux.

```
$ ip
Usage: ip [ OPTIONS ] OBJECT { COMMAND | help }
       ip -V
where  OBJECT := { link | addr | route | neigh }
       OPTIONS := { -4 | -6 }

iproute2mac
Homepage: https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac
This is CLI wrapper for basic network utilities on Mac OS X inspired with iproute2 on Linux systems.
Provided functionality is limited and command output is not fully compatible with iproute2.
For advanced usage use netstat, ifconfig, ndp, arp, route and networksetup directly.
```

#### Examples

Show IP addresses on interface en0.

```
$ ip addr show en0
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 54:46:12:fc:45:12
    inet6 fe80::3636:3bff:fecf:1294/64 scopeid 0x4
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 en0
```

Show details about link en1.

```
$ ip link show en1
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 72:00:08:81:d2:10
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
```

#### References

- [brona/iproute2mac GitHub Page](https://github.com/brona/iproute2mac)

Answer (score 10):

Use the normal command for unix like systems: `ifconfig`.

(Linux also uses ifconfig, but some of the tools have newer versions. `ip` is one of these which one day will replace the old ifconfig.)

Comment: How I could install this ip command on Mac OS? I want some feature like add MAC-VLAN!

Comment: I am not sure you can. The whole world (well, except windows which uses ipconfig and some modern linuxes who use both ip and ifconfig) uses ifconfig. This includes OS X.  I have no mac to test with, but I would look at the commands `vconfig add n0 42` (configure VLAN 42 for the network interface EN0) followed by something like `ifconfig en0.5 1.2.3.3 netmask 255.255.128.0 broadcast 1.2.3.255 up`.

Comment: `ifconfig` outputs quite many unnecessary lines. If IP is everything you need use `ifconfig | grep inet` instead.

Comment: Also, ifconfig is deprecated: https://www.google.de/search?q=ifconfig+deprecated&oq=ifconfig+deprecated&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i59j69i61j69i60l2.5817j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler way without installing any tools:

```
$ which ifconfig
/sbin/ifconfig

$ ifconfig en0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | cut -d ' ' -f2
10.16.45.123
```

Comment: This is the equvalent of `ip address show`, not `ip link` and its subcommands, which the OP asked for…

Answer (score 0):

There is no ip command in Mac. Get it from brew or use:

```
ifconfig en0| grep "inet[ ]" | awk '{print $2}'
```

You can create an alias in `~/.bash_profile` as follows:

```
alias ip-addr="ifconfig en0| grep \"inet[ ]\" | awk '{print \$2}'"
```